# How can I solve -y''-y/|x|=y?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve

$-y''-\frac{y}{|x|}=y$ .

Now $y$ is a function of $x$.
And $|x|$ means the absolute value of $x$, that is, $|x|=x$ for $x>0$, and $-x$ for $x<0$.

Can somebody please hint at some substitution or refer any text related to these type of ode.

**Motivation**:

This ODE comes from quantum mechanics and I need the solution to understand one-dimensional hydrogen atom. Actually, I have to consider

$-\frac{\hbar2}{2m}\psi(x)''-\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon |x|}\psi(x)=E\psi(x)$.

$m,e,\epsilon,\hbar$ are constants. The boundary condition  is $\psi(\infty)=\psi(ー\infty)=0$

Comment: Please make it clear what your equation is.  The one in the title is different from the one in the question.

Comment: $|x|=x$ for $x>0$, and $-x$ for $x<0$.

Comment: Is there a suggested method of solving the ODE that you are required to follow? Or do you want any method that would help with a solution?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to know how to solve the ode.

Comment: To toddler. 
It is correct. $|x|$ means the absolute value of x.

Comment: If it is the one dimensional hydrogen atom, isn't $x$ the radial variable, so always positive?  Then you can remove the absolute value signs and only need a solution for $x \gt 0$.  They probably came from taking the magnitude of the radius vector.  Would you check?  If so, [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%3Dy(1%2B1%2Fx)) gives a solution in terms of confluent hypergeometric and Bessel functions.

Comment: To Ross Millikan.

If the system is three-dimension, the potential is $V(x,y,z)=-\frac{e^2}{4\pi ε \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$. And the Hamiltonian become $H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}　(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{d^2}{dy^2}+\frac{d^2}{dz^2})-\frac{e^2}{4\pi ε \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$.
We usually change polar coordinates, say, $(x,y,z)$ is converted as $(r sinθ cosφ, r sinθ sinφ, r cosθ)$. $r>0,0<θ< \pi,0<φ< 2\pi$ so the Hamiltonian become $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}[ \frac{d^2}{dr^2}+\frac{2}{r} \frac{d}{dr} +\frac{1}{r^2 sinθ} \frac{θ}{dθ}(sinθ \frac{d}{dθ})+\frac{1}{r^2 sin^2θ}\frac{d^2}{dφ^2}]-\frac{e^2}{4\pi ε r}$

Comment: Now, we consider one-dimensional hydrogen atom. The potential of the hydrogen atom is $V(x)=-\frac{e^2}{4\pi ε |x|}$. So Hamiltonian written by orthogonal coordinates is $H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-\frac{e^2}{4\pi ε |x|}$. Now, x can be negative(do you agree with it?). How will the Hamiltonian change if we use polar coordinates in the one-dimensional system?